# DVL as a ranging sensor

Tags: mapping, geometry, sonar, underwater, acoustic-rangefinder

I am trying to use a Doppler Velocity Log (DVL) as a ranging sensor.

The DVL has four acoustic beams with known poses and ranges. This makes it possible to estimate 3D points on the seabed (if the sensor is oriented towards it, let's assume it is). Over time, more and more points accumulate, but are these points actually correct and accurate?

Since the beams have an angular width (e.g., 4 degrees), the intersection between the beam and the floor is not just a point but a surface looking like a circle with a radius proportional to the range. In that case it is not really possible to know exactly where is the point in that circle. Assuming the DVL provides the range to the closest point in that circle (is it actually the case?) could probably help.

It is worth it to estimate this intersection circle or is it negligible? What method could be used to find the point in the circle?

I would appreciate any inputs on this.